# r dygraphs shaded region by time of day across multiple days

Tags: r, dygraphs

In R dygraphs, how do I shade regions by time of day, across multiple days, without listing them each out?  For example, I'd like to shade 07:00 - 08:15 each day in the following example (my full example has many more days).

```
#generate data
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

#generate sample data
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778632/r-xts-generating-1-minute-time-series-from-second-events
x <- xts(cumsum(rnorm(400000, 0, 0.2)), Sys.time() - 400000:1)
x <- to.minutes(x)

#display dygraph
dygraph(x) %>%
  dyCandlestick() %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height=20)
```

Thanks!

Comment: ``Error in function_list[[i]](value) : 
  could not find function "dyCandlestick"`` I think its deprecated.

Comment: For the purposes of shading, it doesn't matter if it's candlesticks, line chart, bar chart, etc - although candlesticks are very much supported https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-candlestick.html

Comment: Also, sessionInfo shows I'm running **dygraphs_1.1.1.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.  Code is below for reference:

Also, thanks to the following for ideas:

[R xts: generating 1 minute time series from second events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778632/r-xts-generating-1-minute-time-series-from-second-events)

[R How to shade week-end period with dygraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449429/r-how-to-shade-week-end-period-with-dygraphs)

http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/20331/r-dygraphs-dyshading-r-dygraph

---

```
#load libraries
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

#generate sample data
x <- xts(cumsum(rnorm(400000, 0, 0.2)), Sys.time() - 400000:1)
x <- to.minutes(x)

#display dygraph without shading
dygraph(x) %>%
  dyCandlestick() %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height=20)


#####################
#function to creating shading in a list
add_shades <- function(x, periods, ...) {
  for( period in periods ) {
    x <- dyShading(x, from = period$from , to = period$to, ... )
  }
  x
}

#####################
#creates the list that feeds into the "add_shades" function
ok_periods<-0
i=1
j=1
while (i<(length(index(x[(.indexhour(x)==9 & .indexmin(x)==30)])))){
  ok_periods[j] <- list(list(from = index(x[(.indexhour(x)==16 & .indexmin(x)==15)][i]), to = index(x[(.indexhour(x)==9 & .indexmin(x)==30)][i+1])))
  i=i+1
  j=j+1
}

#####################
#graph with shading
dygraph(x) %>%
  dyCandlestick() %>%
  add_shades(ok_periods, color = "#FFFFCC" ) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height=20)
```

Comment: One other link that proved helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871572/subsetting-tricks-for-xts-in-r

Answer (score 0):

This is great! I am trying to do something very similar, except I have month/day ranges across multiple years. It must be possible to index months and days in a similar fashion?

```
head(dailyprecipxts)
               [,1]
2002-01-01  16.2199
2002-01-06  48.7243
2002-01-11 105.5646
2002-01-16   7.0446
2002-01-21  47.3491
2002-01-26  21.2664
```

I'd like to create the ok_periods list of the form:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$from
[1] "2002-07-01"

[[1]]$to
[1] "2002-10-01"


[[2]]
[[2]]$from
[1] "2003-07-01"

[[2]]$to
[1] "2003-10-01"
```

The months/day ranges are the same for each year, and unlike the previous example, I have no time-of-day information.